# Messaging an unbound service from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I currently have two services in my android application, which for simplicity I'll call `DataService`, and `CommunicationService`. `DataService` retrieves data from a content provider, which it then serializes and passes on to `CommunicationService`. `CommunicationService` then takes the serialized data and divides it into packets, which it sends to a third-party device one packet at a time. The way that `CommunicationService` knows to send the next packet is through a `BroadcastReceiver`.

`CommunicationService` is started by `DataService` but is unbound and has a longer lifetime than `DataService` (which ends as soon as it has started `CommunicationService`). What is the best way for the `BroadcastReceiver` to call a method on `CommunicationService` to let it know that it's time to send the next packet? Two of the ideas that I've seen are:

- Bind the service in the BroadcastReceiver, call the method, and unbind it. This seems to be best case incredibly bad practice and worst case not feasible.
- `peekService`, although it appears this only works with a service that has been bound at least once, which rules it out.

I know that this architecture might seem a little confusing, but the goal for `CommunicationService` is to be able to reuse it across multiple apps that communicate with a third-party device; as a result, it can't be too tightly bound to a specific implementation.

Comment: You cannot call `context.bindService()` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. Can you explain why you can't just call `startService()` from your receiver? Even if the service is already running, it will receive a call to `onStartCommand()`

Comment: I was under the impression that `startService()` would start a new instance of a service - didn't realize it just signaled an existing one. This seems like the easiest solution so I might end up going with it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BroadcastReceiver` may timeout, so better to have it call an `IntentService`

Since your goal is to have this service provide updates for more than one app, each app should register with the service (which notifies it of potential updates) and then the service should provide a callback to each registered app.

The callback can be specified by the `CommunicationService` and perform whatever functions you like, following the standard serialization restrictions for cross process communication, which you seem to be aware of.

So the basic "flow" would be something like:

Register -> respond with callback
`BroadcastReceiver` -> `IntentService' -> execute callback ->`CommunicationService'

The main issue with calling anything directly from the `BroadcastReceiver` is that your `CommunicationService` may have died, possibly leading to either a timeout or NPE. With the callback, it can check to see if the service is alive and if not, create it. The `IntentReceiver` should be wakeful. And providing a callback object allows you more control over thread-safe code for situations where there are multiple, simultaneous calls and/or data queuing.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly:

`CommunicationService` should extend `IntentService`. It provides the definition for a callback (either through an interface or an inner class that the clients of the service must implement). It provides a mechanism for registering a callback (perhaps a static public function that starts the service if it doesn't exist already) and a mechanism for triggering the next packet to be sent (likely by an Intent?).

(I can't find anything on `IntentReceiver` besides a post that suggests it's deprecated)

Comment: Yes - I meant `IntentService` - I edited my post where I made that mistake. You should be careful with having it define a callback through an interface because not all clients will properly implement serialization, which is required. However, you may be able to define flexible callback object API's that are properly serialized, depending on your use-case.

Comment: Awesome, I think that makes sense then! Thanks for the help.